# StreetViewPanorama's little man marker is _sometimes_ not centered

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Very odd issue here, any advice on how I can investigate this further will be welcome.

I am using google.maps.Map and google.maps.StreetViewPanorama to make a simple interactive tool whose objectives are too long to explain. See an example of this working [here](https://digital-contraptions-imaginarium.github.io/OLAF-yr2_lab/index.html?mbr=%7B%22minX%22%20:%20-0.259116325956696%2C%20%22minY%22%20:%2051.6624820907246%2C%20%22maxX%22%20:%20-0.258678396147402%2C%20%22maxY%22%20:%2051.66269758781%7D&nodes=%5B%7B%22lon%22%20:%20-0.258897437249439%2C%20%22lat%22%20:%2051.6625429779254%7D%2C%7B%22lon%22%20:%20-0.258897437249439%2C%20%22lat%22%20:%2051.6625429779254%7D%2C%7B%22lon%22%20:%20-0.258897437249439%2C%20%22lat%22%20:%2051.6625429779254%7D%2C%7B%22lon%22%20:%20-0.258897437249439%2C%20%22lat%22%20:%2051.6625429779254%7D%5D). The little man figure marking the location of the street view is at the center of the map in the left pane. That is achieved at the moment I create the object by doing:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("name-of-div-container"),
    {
        "center": startLocation,
        "zoom": 18
    });
```

It looks like this:

[image: This is how it looks when it works]

BUT when I load exactly the same URL in an IFRAME as part of some other page (that I cannot show you), the little man is not at the center, but in the top left corner of the map, to the point of being hidden!

[image: This is how it looks when it fails]

There are no relevant JavaScript errors I see in the console that can suggest what went wrong. The full code is [here](https://github.com/Digital-Contraptions-Imaginarium/OLAF-yr2_lab).

Any ideas? The application is not really usable with the marker starting in a hidden position. Thanks!

Giacecco

Comment: The map div doesn't have a size.  When it has zero size the center appears in the upper left corner.

Comment: @geocodezip that's a fantastic intuition, thanks! The DIV actually have width and height specified as a %, but it may be, that at the moment of rendering, the container IFRAME is not yet "instanciated" or something, and its dimensions are still 0px x 0px. I will try working around that and get back here to share what I found.

Comment: What is element(s) is the iframe contained by?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including any CSS/HTML required.

Comment: I will come back with example code. In the meantime, the answer to your question is that the container is code I can't change, as it is generated by a templating system I have no control over. The only way I managed to make the whole thing work for the time being is artificially delaying creating the map and panorama objects by 1 second from the completion of (the IFRAME) page load. Not only this is ugly but I am not sure it is robust either, e.g. what will happen on web browsers running on low performance devices?